# Apache.NMS.XML errors when running in an IIS 10 hosted .net app. Reason: 2381

Tags: .net, iis, ibm-mq, xms

I recently migrated our applications to a new server, which runs IIS 10 (previous version IIS 7.5).
Now my api web applications fail to connect to our IBM MQ Queue Manager, via the apache NMS.XML package (CompCode: 2, Reason: 2381, IBM.XMS.XMSException: CWSMQ0006E).

I tried running the code in a console app (same .net version, server, domain, and user), in which case it runs fine. It only fails on our IIS hosted web apps.

Below are the errors that results from the web application failing to connect to the queue manager.

Error from MQ Client:

```
Process(5432.6) User(service-account) Program(w3wp.exe)
                      Host(development-server) Installation(Installation1)
                      VRMF(7.5.0.3)
AMQ9647: I/O error on SSL key repository.
```

Error from Apache.NMS.XML package:

```
Connect: Failed to establish connection to JMS destination
 Apache.NMS.NMSException: CWSMQ0006E: An exception was received during the call to the method ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection: CompCode: 2, Reason: 2381.
During execution of the specified method an exception was thrown by another component.
See the linked exception for more information. ---> IBM.XMS.XMSException: CWSMQ0006E: An exception was received during the call to the method ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection: CompCode: 2, Reason: 2381.
During execution of the specified method an exception was thrown by another component.
See the linked exception for more information.
   at IBM.XMS.Client.WMQ.Factories.WmqConnectionFactory.CreateProviderConnection(XmsPropertyContext connectionProps)
   at IBM.XMS.Client.Impl.XmsConnectionFactoryImpl.CreateConnection(String userID, String password)
   at IBM.XMS.Client.Impl.XmsConnectionFactoryImpl.CreateConnection()
   at Apache.NMS.XMS.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection() in c:\dev\wec-integraton\Messaging\XMS\apache-src\src\main\csharp\ConnectionFactory.cs:line 1418
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Apache.NMS.XMS.Util.ExceptionUtil.WrapAndThrowNMSException(Exception ex) in c:\dev\wec-integraton\Messaging\XMS\apache-src\src\main\csharp\Util\ExceptionUtil.cs:line 139
   at Apache.NMS.XMS.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection() in c:\dev\wec-integraton\Messaging\XMS\apache-src\src\main\csharp\ConnectionFactory.cs:line 1424
```

Comment: 7.5 has been out of support since 2018.  The error says `AMQ9647: I/O error on SSL key repository`, do you have a permission error accessing your key store?

Comment: Yeah I was able to confirm permissions by checking the security of the key store manually, and adding some test lines to the code to access the keystore files individually. 
I'm having a hard time understanding why this identical code would work in a console app, but not in the IIS hosted app.

Comment: Did iis run under the same user?